# Relative growth rate from standard growth rate equation

Tags: calculus, mathematical-modeling

Right, I have a plant growth equation which looks like this:
$$
y = d + \frac{a - d}{\left[\, 1 + \left(\, x/c\,\right)^{b}\,\right]^g}
$$
where

[image: A table describing parameter function]

[from this paper by Gottschalk & Dunn 2005](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003269705003313).

- I want to identify the relative growth rate - that is the rate of growth based on the current mass ($y$) and **not** on the length of time the plant has been growing ($x$).
- This would mean I could come up with an arbitrary value for $y$, and determine how it would change over the next unit of $x$ regardless of where on the $x$ axis it lies.

I *think* that this is $(\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x)/y$ but to be honest, my maths skills are not really up to it.

Can anybody help ?. Thanks !.

Comment: Looks good to me! Do you know how to calculate the derivative?

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely at sea!

Comment: You could just ask Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+d%2B%5Cfrac%7B%28a-d%29%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bc%7D%29%5Eb%5Cright%29%5Eg%7D

Comment: OK, that gives me d/dx do I just divide the total by y? and what about the x on the other side of the equation?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it. And it won't hurt to write $x/b$ as
$$
\frac{x}{b} = \left( \left( \frac{a-d}{y-d} \right)^{1/g} -1 \right)^{1/b}
$$
It will be quite a complicated expression ...

Comment: do you mean x/c?

Comment: ah, yes, sorry. It was a typo.